# Limiting the sed search to 2 nd column in a file

Tags: sed

Below is the content of ma file (sample.txt):

```
CQUAD4   5600000 560005  5602371 5602367 5602374 5602372 0.     -1.75
CQUAD4   5600003 560005  5600000 5602367 5602374 5602372 0.     -1.75
```

Am using the below command:

```
sed -i "s@\(\s*\w*\s*\)\(5600000\)\(\s*\)\([0-9]*\)\(.*\)@\1\2\36000   \5@g" sample.txt
```

I want to restrict the pattern matching `5600000` to only second column and then do a replace with '6000   '.

Can somebody help me...please

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution with GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed). Anchor the search to start of line with `^`.

```
sed -i -r  "s@^(\s*\S+\s+)5600000\s+@\16000 @" sample.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` might be a little more natural for this:

```
awk '$2=="5600000"{$2="6000";print} 1' sample.txt
```

That basically says "if the second field is 5600000, replace it with 6000 and print the line, otherwise just print the line".

The one downside I see is that this might, depending on your version of `awk`, collapse multiple spaces down to one, which may mess with the alignment of your columns. You'll have to decide if that's a problem or not...

Comment: Thank you guys :) it worked for me by just limiting my search to the beginning of the line using '^':sed -i "s@^\(\s*\w*\s*\)\($1\)\(\s*\)\([0-9]*\)\(.*\)@\1\2\3$formatted_replace_string\5@g" replace_file